# jquery - find whether a particular ajax call triggered from click on one of multiple elements finishes

Tags: jquery, ajax, click

Suppose in HTML I have:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-lang="en" class="load_more load_more_en">Element EN</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-lang="bn" class="load_more load_more_bn">Element BN</a>
```

In JS I have :

```
$(".load_more").click(function(){

    $elem=$(this);
    var data_lang = $elem.attr('data-lang');

    $.ajax({

         method:"POST",
         url:"/myurl",
         data:{data_lang:data_lang},

         success:function(response){

         },
         error:function(response){

         }
    });
});
```

The ajax call can be triggered by clicking on any of the `load_more` class elements.

Suppose the user clicks on `load_more_en` class element and triggers an ajax call. I do not want to trigger another call by the next click on  `load_more_en` until the first one finishes.

But the user can still click on `load_more_bn` class element to trigger another ajax request at the same time. Only when the ajax call from click on the `load_more_en` element finishes, that the user should be able to trigger another ajax request clicking on the `load_more_en` element.

If there was only 1 element (i.e. `load_more_en`), I could do it in the following way :

```
can_do_ajax=1;
$(".load_more").click(function(){

    $elem=$(this);
    var data_lang = $elem.attr('data-lang');

    if(can_do_ajax){

        can_do_ajax=0;

        $.ajax({

            method:"POST",
            url:"/myurl",
            data:{data_lang:data_lang},

            success:function(response){
                can_do_ajax=1;

            },
            error:function(response){
                can_do_ajax=1;
            }

        });

    }// end of if

});
```

But now that there are two elements with the same class, how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can place a class on the element when it's clicked, before the AJAX request is sent. This class can then set a disabled-like state in the UI. You can also check for this class in the click handler (should someone attempt to bypass the CSS rule) to ensure that only one request can be made per `a` element. You can then remove that class when the AJAX call completes. Try this:

```js
$(".load_more").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $elem = $(this);
  if ($elem.hasClass('ajax-pending'))
    return;

  $elem.addClass('ajax-pending');
  var data_lang = $elem.data('lang');
  console.log(`loading ${data_lang}`);

  // mock AJAX call for this demo...
  setTimeout(function() {
    // imagine this is the complete handler:
    $elem.removeClass('ajax-pending');
    console.log(`${data_lang} loaded`);
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
.ajax-pending {
  color: #CCC;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-lang="en" class="load_more load_more_en">Element EN</a>

<a href="#" data-lang="bn" class="load_more load_more_bn">Element BN</a>
```

Note here the use of `data()` instead of `attr()` to get the data attributes and `preventDefault()` instead of `javascript:void(0)` in the `href` attribute of the `a` element.

Comment: suppose the user clicks on `load_more_en` and `ajax-pending-class` is added to that element and an ajax request is made. Then the user clicks on `load_more_bn` and 2nd ajax request is made. The 1st request takes longer time to finish than the 2nd one. Will  the `success` callback of the 2nd request remove the `ajax-pending` class only from `load_more_bn`  or from both `load_more_en` and `load_more_bn` ?

Comment: It will only remove it from the button relevant to that AJAX request - you can see this in the above example if you click one link, then the other.